# .NET Core Selenium WebDriver not found

Tags: selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I've converted an NUnit test project from .NET Framework to .NET Core. When I try to execute a Selenium test using Visual Studio, I am seeing this error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The chromedriver.exe
>   file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the
>   PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

I've included the `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` Nuget Package and `chromedriver.exe` appears in the output bin folder. Without having to set the ChromeDriver url as an environment variable, how do I get Visual Studio to find the file?

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   var driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: While I don't want to do it as a solution, even adding chromedriver.exe to PATH variable doesn't work.

Comment: How do you instantiate the driver? Post your relevant code.

Comment: I believe installing it manually into your PATH is safer than relying on a 3rd party NuGet author package. Or downloading the exe from Google and putting it into your project manually.
You can try using `new ChromeDriver('.')` which will look at the CWD where the program is executed from.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because in .Net Core the NuGet packages are loaded from a global location instead of the packages folder in .NET Framework projects.

You can use the following and it will run correctly:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
        var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(currentDirectory);        
        driverService.Start();
        var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService);
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did when i had the problem was to set a var:

```
var driverDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

And just pass it to ChromeDriver on creation.

Comment: This changes the error to `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:49416/
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to determine the problem. Please post your code.