# Python program can't find chromedriver from when run from cmd prompt

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, filepath

thanks for reading! I've created a python program using selenium that uploads a file onto a website automatically. I've placed the .py file and chrome driver in a folder on my desktop and set my executable path to "chromedriver.exe". When I run the program from IDLE, the program runs without any issue. When I try to run it from the command line, however, the program cannot find the chromedriver. I've placed them in that folder because I'd like to share the thing with my co-workers and plan on using a VBA script from an Excel to call the python program and pass some variables. My assumption is that since all the files are in the same folder, path would not be an issue.

How do I make it so that all path dependencies are eliminated?

Comment: Did you check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925604/net-core-selenium-webdriver-not-found. Though its a .NET based solution but the same is helpful for Python where in Python pass chromedriver path as string in ```.get()``` method as argument

Comment: @JenilDave The thing is when I get the current working directory, it isn't the location of the .py file

Answer (score 0):

You should try to specify full path to chromedriver.exe like C:\users\username\Desktop\projectfolder\chromedriver.exe

Comment: I want to share this with people so the path of chromedrivers will vary, which is why I've placed it in the same folder as the .py file. Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Try to specify path as driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'./chromedriver.exe'). With ./ at the beginning